# NSJSONSerialization not storing data into array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have this code in `AppDelegate.m` :

```
    NSError *error;
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"City" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];


    NSLog(@"data : %@",data);
    NSLog(@"json : %@",json[0]);
```

And `data` has content but `NSJSONSerialization` is not storing it into variable `json` (it shows `(null)`)

My json file content :

```
[

“Result”:
 {
   "ID":"3",
   "Name":"Ambegaon",
   "Distid":"1050114"
 },
 {
   "ID":"4",
   "Name":"Aundh",
   "Distid":"1050114"
 }
]
```

Things i have tried:

1. `NSDictionary` `NSArray` both mutable and non mutable
2. Changed City.json location
3. Different options like `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` `kNilOptions`

Comment: I advise you to use AFNeworking as it parse and gives you the dictionary automatically

Comment: You didn't read the `error` parameter. The JSON you gave is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because your JSON has invalid format. It not equal array. You need have

```
[
 {
   "ID":"3",
   "Name":"Ambegaon",
   "Distid":"1050114"
 },
 {
   "ID":"4",
   "Name":"Aundh",
   "Distid":"1050114"
 }
]
```

without `Result` key or change your json and parse code to

```
{
   "Result" : [{
      "ID":"3",
      "Name":"Ambegaon",
      "Distid":"1050114"
    },
    {
      "ID":"4",
      "Name":"Aundh",
      "Distid":"1050114"
    }]
}

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSArray *arr = json[@"Result"];
```

Comment: Trying to store the result of a call to `jsonObjectWithData` in the wrong type of variable will not cause it to fail. The `jsonObjectWithData` function returns an object of type id. It will cause other problems, but that isn't the cause of getting back a nil. The JSON data must be malformed.

Answer (score 0):

The method `jsonObjectWithData` will fail if the JSON data is badly formed.

There must be something wrong with the syntax of your JSON data. You can convert the NSData to a string and log that. You might also check the error you're getting back from the function.